# Why won't it POST my data successfully even though it works on Postman?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I've tested my endpoint on Postman with the correct key and value and it works fine.  However, when I try to make the POST request on the browser - I get a `500` error.

The `console.log(id);` and `console.log(email);` are both printing correct values so I can rule out that this isn't the issue.  I've also tried using `Axios` to make the POST request but it kept giving me problems so I restored to `fetch` instead.  I'm open to any suggestions on improving my code :).

How can I make my post request go through successfully on the browser?  I'm probably overlooking something

frontend code:

```
fileUpload(file) {
    const formData = new FormData()
    let id = Cookies.get("id");
    let email = Cookies.get("email");

    console.log(id);
    console.log(email);

    formData.append('file', file);

    this.setState({
        id: id,
        email: email,
        formData: formData
    });

    let data = {
        "id": this.state.id,
        "email" : this.state.email,
        "formData": this.state.fData
    }

    fetch('http://myendpoint/api/auth/wall-of-fame', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => { console.error(error) });
}
```

backend code:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $email = Auth::user()->email;

    $data= [
        'file_path' => $filePath,
        'user_id' => $id,
        'email' => $email
    ];

    DB::table('my db')->insert($data);
    echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Can you check your server log to get more information about what caused the 500 error?

Comment: @Don'tPanic yeah here's what it says `local.ERROR: Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null` but now sure how this can be.

Comment: What are the values of - file('file') and $request?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using form data to upload the file, it's better to add other attributes to the form data  itself as below rather than creating an array

```
formData.append('file', file)
formData.set('id', id)
formData.set('email', email)
```

and further, in the request, you can send the formData as the body

```
fetch('http://myendpoint/api/auth/wall-of-fame', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
})
```

this should solve your issue. Let me know

Comment: Ah ok, I see!  but in my server logs I'm getting `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`.  I need to figure out why.

Comment: I'm not sure, but in the backend code, it looks like you are not getting the `id` and `email` from the request

Answer (score 0):

use @wk24 answer from Frontend and in the backend code you are using AUTH to get user id instead of $request, i think you should use

`$request->id;`
`$email = $request->email;`
Hope this solves your problem

Comment: I tried that already but I keep getting back `null` when I run `dd();`.  AUTH is the only way that returns correct values when running `dd();`